# Getting http 404 Error when creating a MVC 5 Empty Controller and in the browser giving the url to the controller

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace IndentityDemo.Controllers
{
    public class SecretController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Secret/
        public ContentResult Secret()
        {
            return Content("This is secret...");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm writing code in VS2013. I've created a controller named SecretController.
After build.. I've write url in browser .. "http://localhost:14516/Secret/Secret" but it give me the Error as bellow:

Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Secret/Secret

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1586.0

My HomeController Working fine. But Controller can't be reached. Even when I attach a break point to the controller method it giving me a warning that 'The breakpoint will not currently be hit'

Please help me resolve this problem.

Comment: Rebuild your project and try ???? Did you alter the default route registration code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
public SecretController() { }
```

before your `Secret()`